# Mixed cumulative distribution [picture added]

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

Since $F(x)=pF_d(x)+(1-p)F_c(x)$, so $p=0.3$?
I wonder if there is no more information except $F(x)$'s graph then how we can find $p$?

Comment: You question is not clear. So let me make a guess. Is $p$ the probability that your random variable is equal to $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficient $p$ is the total mass of the discrete part of the distribution. Thus, $p$ equals the sum of the heights of the jumps of $F$. In the present case, $F$ has one jump of height $0.3$ hence $p=0.3$. Furthermore, $F_d$ is the CDF of the unit Dirac mass at $x$ where the jump occurs, hence $F_d(t)=0$ if $t\lt x$ and $F_d(t)=1$ if $t\geqslant x$.